# When my receiver that I have hooked up to my pc turns on it causes my monitors to turn black is there a way to stop this?

Tags: windows, windows-10, nvidia-graphics-card

So I have my PC hooked up to my receiver via HDMI to display my screen on my TV. But anytime the receiver is turned on all my screens go plank for a period of time is there a way to prevent this?

I have an Nvidia GTX 980Ti and Two Monitors the TV is set to mirror the main screen.

The HDMI cable for the TV is run to a Denon avr-x3200w receiver. Then from the receiver to the TV.

My PC fully recognizes the Denon avr-x3200w in the Nvidia settings.

It just when the receiver is turned on everything goes black and same for when its turning off. Its like its causing the graphics to reset.

Comment: Have you tried plugging it in and then turning on the computer?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a receiver?

Comment: It could be that a microsoft update could have installed other drivers for you card. You might want uninstall, then reinstall the drivers which came with the card. https://video-nvidia.com/en-us/series_900/nvidia-geforce-gtx-980-ti.html

Comment: @ramhound Audio Video Receiver. More specifically a Denon avr-x3200w. Use it to switch between audio video devices and to power audio equipment.

Comment: @vssher all drivers are fresh drivers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Windows detects a new monitor, all monitor screens will go black for a second, and then it will come back with your new monitor detected and usable. I don't believe there is a way to disable this (maybe in the registry?), so my best suggestion is to turn on your receiver, and then turn on your computer. Alternately you could just keep your receiver on at all times, but it is up to you.

Edit: Forgot to add this suggestion. Try using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> when it happens, this pretty much restarts the graphics driver.

Comment: That is unfortunate I even tried to run it through a separate graphics processor and the same result.

Comment: @MatthewLozoya Sorry to hear that, if the screen is blanking for more than a second then I would suggest the keyboard command to try and reset that driver. I do believe though that this is something that isn't identified as a bug for Windows, so you are most likely out of luck.

Comment: So apparently this has been an issue since Windows 7 there have been registry fixes but they don't exist in the current version of windows.

Comment: The only current solutions are to own a workstation graphics card where you can simulate the edid of the monitor to make it appear always on. Or what other users have said works is a device called Monitor Detect Killer I ordered one but man MS needs to fix this.

Comment: @MatthewLozoya Have you tried the HDMI pin 19 trick? When searching the device I stumbled upon it on reddit, and it does seem to work. [Link](https://www.reddit.com/r/htpc/comments/7a7zhk/til_about_the_hdmi_pin_19_hotplugblocking_trick/)

Comment: yes I have tried the pin 19 trick that also did not work :/